# Unable to profile MySQL with MiniProfiler on .NET Core

Tags: mysql, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, mvc-mini-profiler

I'm playing with **.net core** and trying to get **asp.net core** + **mysql** + **dapper** + **mini-mvc-profiler** to work on **Linux**. Having problem with mini-mvc-profiler.

I'm using:

```
<PackageReference Include="Dapper" Version="1.50.2" />
<PackageReference Include="MiniProfiler.AspNetCore" Version="4.0.0-alpha6-79" />
<PackageReference Include="MiniProfiler.Shared" Version="4.0.0-alpha6-79" />
<PackageReference Include="MySql.Data.Core" Version="7.0.4-IR-191" />
```

I have SQLProfiler class:

```
public class SQLProfiler
{
    public static DbConnection GetOpenConnection(string connectionString)
    {
        //return new MySqlConnection(connectionString); // that works OK         
        return new StackExchange.Profiling.Data.ProfiledDbConnection( 
            new MySqlConnection(connectionString), MiniProfiler.Current
        );
    }
}
```

And calling it from repository class:

```
using (var connection = SQLProfiler.GetOpenConnection(_connectionString))
{              
    return connection.Query<UserIdentityDTO>(sql, 
        new {
            myemail = email,
            mypassword = password,
            myprovider = PROVIDER_LOCAL
        }
    ).FirstOrDefault();                 
}
```

I get:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.set_Reader(MySqlDataReader value)
```

StackTrace:

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.set_Reader(MySqlDataReader value)
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ResetReader()
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.Dispose(bool disposing)
StackExchange.Profiling.Data.ProfiledDbCommand.Dispose(bool disposing) in ProfiledDbCommand.cs
System.Data.Common.DbCommand.Dispose()
Dapper.SqlMapper+<QueryImpl>d__124.MoveNext()
System.Collections.Generic.List..ctor(IEnumerable<T> collection)
System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source)
Dapper.SqlMapper.Query<T>(IDbConnection cnn, string sql, object param, IDbTransaction transaction, bool buffered, Nullable<int> commandTimeout, Nullable<CommandType> commandType)
persistance.dapper.repository.UserQueries.Get(string email, string password) in UserQueries.cs
```

Comment: Try to wrap the code in `try/catch` and see is there any real error. Right now your real error is overridden by exception in `finally` block during dispose.

Comment: I'm trying to find the source to their library to see what's up. In the meantime, I suggest trying https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/ - it's *actually* `async` and has been pretty good on the .NET Core front. For what it's worth, the MySql.Data.Core package is unlisted now...it may have many issues lingering.

Comment: Thanks. It magically works now!

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Nick Craver,

```
 <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Dapper" Version="1.50.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="DapperExtensions.DotnetCore" Version="1.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="MiniProfiler.AspNetCore" Version="4.0.0-alpha6-79" />
    <PackageReference Include="MiniProfiler.Shared" Version="4.0.0-alpha6-79" />
    <PackageReference Include="MySqlConnector" Version="0.30.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

...it's alive  :-)